# Positive definite matrix implies the **infimum** of eigenvalues are positive?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, supremum-and-infimum, positive-definite

Suppose $P(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is always a positive definite matrix, does it imply that the infimum (over $\mathbb{R}$) of the minimum eigenvalue of $P(x)$ is always positive?, that is, $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{\lambda_{{\rm min}}(P(x)) \} > 0$ In a mathematical way:

Is the following conclusion correct?
\begin{equation}
    \forall x \in \mathbb{R},\;P(x) \succ 0 \implies  \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{\lambda_{{\rm min}}(P(x)) \} > 0
\end{equation}

Please be careful with the infimum.

Please go to the other similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029778/positive-definite-matrix-implies-the-infimum-of-eigenvalues-are-positive-se), which is exactly the real (and more difficult in my opinion) question that I want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $n=1$ and $P(x)=e^x$ or in general, $P(x)=e^{xI_n}$.

Comment: I think it should be $P(x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: @winston $e^x$ is OK. It is always positive and $e^x\to0$ when $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: Yes,you are right.

Comment: Actually my intended question is more difficult. Can you go to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029778/positive-definite-matrix-implies-the-infimum-of-eigenvalues-are-positive-se